# Errors when using InStr() to search HTML

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having difficulty using InStr() for multiple line inputs when searching through HTML code - here's a simplified version of my code with comments showing errors at debug.print:

```
Sub TestInStr()
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html

XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.hltv.org/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48623/masterminds-vs-riotous-raccoons", False
XMLPage.send
If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then MsgBox XMLPage.statusText
html = XMLPage.responseText

Dim str1, str2, str3, str4 As String

'Multi Line HTML
str1 = "<div class=""bold"">Breakdown</div>" & vbCrLf & "                    </div>" & vbCrLf & "                    <div class=""match-info-row"">" & vbCrLf & "                      <div class=""right"">"
str2 = "</div>" & vbCrLf & "                      <div class=""bold"">Team rating</div>"
Debug.Print InStr(html, str1) 'Cant find, value = 0 (Multi Line HTML)
Debug.Print InStr(html, str2) 'Cant find, value = 0 (Multi Line HTML)


'Single Line HTML
str3 = "<div class=""bold"">Breakdown</div>"
str4 = "<div class=""match-info-row"">"
Debug.Print InStr(html, str3) 'Found, value = 15503 (Single Line HTML)
Debug.Print InStr(html, str4) 'Found, value = 15208 (Single Line HTML)
End Sub
```

Here's the source HTML code:

```
            <div class="bold">Breakdown</div>
            </div>
            <div class="match-info-row">
              <div class="right">0.91 : 1.27</div>
              <div class="bold">Team rating</div>
```

As shown, when I try to pass multiple lines of HTML into InStr(), it return's a 0, finding nothing. But if I do the same by breaking the string down into single lines and repeat - it works fine.

Is there any way in which I could pass multiple lines of text into InStr() when searching through HTML and get a return? Thanks

Comment: Have you got the correct number of spaces in your string as in the HTML?  Does the HTML even contain spaces?  (It might just look that way in whatever application you are using to view it.)  Does the HTML contain CR/LF characters or perhaps just LF or just CR characters?  (Or, again, maybe it has neither and it is just the viewer which is showing it as if they are there.)

Comment: You may need to use `vbCr` or `vbLf` instead of `vbCrLf` to match `\n`. You can use `Asc(Mid(html_source, position, 1))` to distinguish a carriage return from a line feed in the source.

Comment: Thank you so much - you guys are great!! vbLf fixed it. If you could please post this as an answer - I will mark it as complete for others reference. Thanks again!

Comment: @YowE3K I copied the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use `vbCr` or `vbLf` instead of `vbCrLf` to match `\n`. You can use `Asc(Mid(html_source, position, 1))` to determine what is used for a newline in the html source.

Hope that helps